# Can't switch off freestyle render lines' transparency - Cycles

Tags: objects, transparency, freestyle

I'm struggling with this render. I'm trying to stop the freestyle render lines from showing through the geometry. Must've been something i pressed, who knows:)

[image]

Heres my settings

[image]

Thanks:)

Comment: Okay. I imported the model into a fresh scene and now its fine. Must be a needle in a haystack tickbox.